# TextWatcher not recognize numbers

Tags: android

I have a fragment with some `EditTexts` that have a `TextWatcher` listener to mask input.

**On a tablet with Android 9**, the `TextWatcher` not recognize numbers and he doesn't write them, instead they are captured by the `dispatchKeyEvent` in the main activity (as if dispatched from an external keyboard).

In other devices this doesn't happen (tested smartphones with Android 10 or 11).

*Fragment class*

`OnViewCreated....`

```
...
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
...
```

*myTextWatcher class*

```
....

 @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
        isDeleting = count > after;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
    {
        if (isRunning || isDeleting) { return; }

        isRunning = true;

        int inputSize = editable.length();
        int inputPos = (inputSize > 0) ? (editable.length() - 1) : 0;

        if ((inputSize < size) && (inputSize > 0)) {
            if ((mask.charAt(inputSize) != '#') &&
                    (mask.charAt(inputSize) != '*')) {
                editable.append(mask.charAt(inputSize));
            }
            else if (mask.charAt(inputSize) == '#') {
                if (!Character.isDigit(editable.charAt(inputPos)))
                    editable.delete(inputPos, inputSize);
            }
            else if (mask.charAt(inputSize) == '*') {
                if ((!Character.isDigit(editable.charAt(inputPos))) && (!Character.isAlphabetic(editable.charAt(inputPos))))
                    editable.delete(inputPos, inputSize);
            }
        } else if (inputSize > size) {
            editable.delete(inputPos, inputSize);
        }

        isRunning = false;
    }
....
```

The `EditText` is set with:
`android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters"`

if I remove this option it writes the numbers in the EditText but the textWatcher doesn't do its job.